# Camera cutting objects

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, camera, shaders

For some reason I cliked on something I shouldn't click and don't know how to undo it. Only happens in shading viewport. On Layout, it looks perfectly fine.

How to undo this?

[image]

Comment: Camera setting -> Clipping Near/Far?

Answer (score 1):

[The Clipping Region](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/sculpt_paint/brush/introduction.html?highlight=clipping%20region#the-clipping-region) works only in Wireframe ans Solid shading modes.

Shortcut **Alt+B** for toggle